# Is there a way to get the visitors city and country in Rails controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-geocoder

In my current app, i use Geocoder gem to get the city and the country of the visitor. I use hidden fields in my view to get these details. When the login form is submitted, these details will be sent to the controller and the controller will save them to the database. When I try to get these details directly from the controller by using

```
 request.location.city
```

It will assigning a blank value to the database. If I use hidden fields in the view, some one can temper with them right? So, how can I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried to use non hidden fields just for debugging?

Answer (score 0):

You should store visitor information before you render any content:

```
class UsersController
  def new
    # I suspect that, for fast insert, you should probably use a NoSQL database
    # to perform `store!` or even just write it to a log file
    Visitor.store!(:city => request.location.city, :ip => request.ip)
  end

  def create
    @user = User.build(params[:user].merge(:city => request.location.city))
    if @user.valid?
      @user.save
      flash[:notice] = "You've been registered!"
      redirect_to user_dashboard_path
    else
      flash[:notice] = "Couldn't register your account"
      render action: "new"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Actually I need to get the details of any visitor to the login page.

Comment: Then you need to log that via the `new` method, not via the `create` method. I'll update my answer.